# How do I get this output from MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a table called nasdaq_transactions looks like below

```
Ticker  Close   Date
GOOG    1195.06 08/15/2018
AAPL    215.15  08/15/2018
MSFT    104.56  08/15/2018
GOOG    1198.11 08/16/2018
AAPL    216.1   08/16/2018
MSFT    105.1   08/16/2018
GOOG    1200.96 08/17/2018
AAPL    217.58  08/17/2018
MSFT    107.58  08/17/2018
```

Want to build a query that gives a output

```
Ticker  08/15/2018  08/16/2018  08/17/2018
GOOG    1196.06      1198.11     1200.96
AAPL    215.15       216.1       217.58
MSFT    104.56       105.1       107.58
```

Comment: Don't know why the format is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can transform data from multiple rows into columns.

In SQL Server you can use the **PIVOT** function to transform the data from rows to columns:

```
select * from
    (
  select Ticker, Date
  from nasdaq_transactions
   ) 
pivot
    (
  max(value)
  for columnname in ('08/15/2018', '08/16/2018', '08/17/2018')
  ) piv;
```

I have given you a sample code. Refer to it and apply accordingly.

Comment: When I ran your code I got "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(max(value) for column in ('08/15/2018', '08/16/2018', '08/17/2018'"

Comment: This is not exact code. this is for reference kindly apply accordingly and then run